# Hive returning no results on a simple select query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table called `processed`. The last column is named as `monthid`. The data type for this column is `bigint`. When I fire a simple query like this, I get no results:

```
select * from processed where monthid = 5 ;
```

A few rows for the table have been shown below. Can someone suggest what's wrong here?

```
11741   Negative    11  69.55   1401172919  48  27  5
11741   Negative    11  102.0   1401172997  48  27  5
11741   Negative    11  145.78  1401173093  48  27  5
11741   Negative    11  70.54   1401173137  49  27  5
11741   Negative    11  85.2    1401173146  49  27  5
11741   Negative    11  67.47   1401173156  49  27  5
11741   Negative    11  92.76   1401173223  49  27  5
```

As can be seen from the above sample data, the last column has `monthid = 5`. However, my query returns me nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem here was that i had partitioned the above table based on column #6. Hence, due to either permissions issue or something funky, the query was returning nothing. After, I dropped the table and created it again without the partition, the above query worked fine. For more information on this, please refer to

[Hive - Queries on Partitions return nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201472/hive-queries-on-partions-returns-nothing)